# how to get key and value data using JPA repository entity model?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I wrote a query:

```
select c.ContactID as key,c.ContactName as value 
from com.seismic.crm.model.Contact c inner join c.account ca 
where ca.accountId = :accountId
```

and got the following exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: 
account of: com.seismic.crm.model.Contact
```

Comment: Post your model classes also to get the overview

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA Repositories Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795345/jpa-repositories-exception)